# Is there a way to show the red status bar without recording?

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

What I want is that when my app just enter background, showing a notification view with custom text and keeping stay for few seconds. It can be look like banner notification or the red status bar with recording/calling. Is that possible? Any idea? Thanks.

here is the UI effect what I want  [image]

Comment: The only similar thing you can do is using `Local Notification`. [Read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html).

Comment: Local Notification can not be specified last period, I mean how to keep showing. show again after disappear?

Comment: Either you want a local notification, or the screen you show is for special "background" work still on, and you can't do it except if you use one of these (like location, call, etc.)

Comment: Thank Larme, As I know, app can keep runing in background about 10 minute.